¿Cómo se puede convertir el valor de las variables int a string y viceversa en C#?
using System;

public class Hello
{
    public static void Main(string [] args) {
        
        Console.WriteLine ("Select your age.");
        string Age = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("\nSelect your money."); 
        string Money = Console.ReadLine();
        
        if (Age <= 18 && Money <= 4500) {
            Console.WriteLine("\nYou can buy the house");
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("You can't buy your house");
        }
    }
}

¿Cómo convierto el valor de la edad del usuario de int a string y viceversa?

El valor que se obtiene al teclear el usuario Money o Age es de tipo string, pero la comparación la realizas incorrectamente, ya que tienes que convertir los valores de string a int.

Puedes usar el método ToString de cualquier objeto para convertirlo en un string.
Para convertir un string a número puedes usar el método Parse de la clase int o TryParse para que no produzca excepciones.
Por ejemplo:
Console.WriteLine("\nSelect your money."); 
string Money = Console.ReadLine();

// Opción 1
int nMoney = int.Parse(Money);
// Opción 2
if (int.TryParse(out int nMoney)){
    // El número se convirtió correctamente 
    ...
}

Estos métodos están disponibles en todas las clases numéricas, incluso en las de punto flotante.

Al usar Console.ReadLine() estas obteniendo un valor tipo string pero para comparar la edad y el dinero debes realizar una conversión a int, puedes usar  Convert.ToInt32 o int.TryParse
public class Hello { public static void Main(string [] args) {
        
       Console.WriteLine ("Select your age.");
        string ageInput = Console.ReadLine();
        
        Console.WriteLine("\nSelect your money."); 
        string moneyInput = Console.ReadLine();
        
      if (int.TryParse(ageInput, out int age) && int.TryParse(moneyInput, out int money)) //*Convierte valores de string a int
       {
        if (age <= 18 && money <= 4500) { ///*Compara
        
            Console.WriteLine("\nYou can buy the house");
        }
        
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("You can't buy your house");
        }   
      }
       else
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Verifique un valor correcto para \"age\" and \"money\".");
       }
            
   }
}

